# Neo4J / Cypher need hel writing a query that shows all the result nodes that connect to an initial node by a specific number of paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4J, how do I write a Cypher query that shows all the nodes that connect to an initial node by a specific number of paths?

Answer (score 1):

Number of paths or number of hops?

```
start n=node(x)
match path = n-[:TYPE*..3]->end // number of hops *..3 is up to 3 hops
return path
limit 10 // number of paths
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing but returning only simple paths (no repeated nodes)? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767748/returning-only-simple-paths-in-neo4j-cypher-query

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe he's looking for:

```
start n=node(x) 
match path = n-[*]->end      // maybe specify a max length and type?
with count(path) as cnt, end // group by end node, get count of paths
where cnt = <numpaths>       // replace <numpaths> with the number of paths you want to match
return end
```