# Returning only simple paths in Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, traversal, cypher

Given a query like the following:

```
START n = node(123)
MATCH p = n-[r:LIKES*..3]->x
RETURN p;
```

The result paths that I get with the query above contain cycles.

How can I return only simple paths?

Given this [example](http://console.neo4j.org?init=(Neo)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Neo%22%20%7D%0A(Morpheus)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%22Morpheus%22%7D%0A(Trinity)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%22Trinity%22%7D%0A(Cypher)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%22Cypher%22%7D%0A(Smith)%20%7B%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Agent%20Smith%22%7D%0A(Architect)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%22The%20Architect%22%7D%0A(0)-%5B%3AROOT%5D-%3E(Neo)%0A(Neo)-%5B%3AKNOWS%5D-%3E(Morpheus)%0A(Morpheus)-%5B%3AKNOWS%5D-%3E(Neo)%0A(Neo)-%5B%3ALOVES%5D-%3E(Trinity)%0A(Morpheus)-%5B%3AKNOWS%5D-%3E(Trinity)%0A(Morpheus)-%5B%3AKNOWS%5D-%3E(Cypher)%0A(Trinity)-%5B%3AKNOWS%5D-%3E(Morpheus)%0A(Cypher)-%5B%3AKNOWS%5D-%3E(Smith)%0A(Smith)-%5B%3ACODED_BY%5D-%3E(Architect)&query=START%20neo%3Dnode(1)%20MATCH%20path%3D%20neo-%5Br%3AKNOWS*..4%5D-%3Eother%20RETURN%20neo%2C%20LENGTH(path)%20AS%20length%2C%20EXTRACT(p%20in%20NODES(path)%20%3A%20p.name)%2C%20other%20ORDER%20BY%20length%0A&version=):

- How can I avoid paths with repeated nodes like: [Neo, Morpheus, Trinity, Morpheus, Neo]

Comment: Note that the path length 3 is a query parameter thet can change

Comment: Do you have an example using console.neo4j.org/usage.html?

Comment: @PeterNeubauer just added one!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Specifying the uniqueness of paths is a planned feature of cypher.

So right now we have to ascertain that no node is a duplicate in the path.

There is an `ALL` predicate that must hold true for all elements of a collection (which a path is).
And with `filter` you can extract the elements of an collection for that a certain condition holds true.

```
START neo=node(1) 
MATCH path= neo-[r:KNOWS*..4]->other 
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) where 
          1=length(filter(m in nodes(path) : m=n))) 
RETURN neo, LENGTH(path) AS length, EXTRACT(p in NODES(path) : p.name), other 
ORDER BY length
```

So what I did was:

- For all nodes of the path `n`
- Filter the path for the nodes that are equal to `n`
- determine the `length` of that collection
- assert with `ALL` that it has to be ONE for each `n`

see: http://console.neo4j.org/r/dpalbl

Comment: Hi Michael, Is there any other better way to identify cycles in path. The solution shared above by you, works fine but, is costly in terms of time & db hits. Can u please check?

Comment: While working with Neo4j 2.2.5 I had to change the filter part to `filter(m in nodes(path) WHERE m=n))`

Comment: Hi. Does anyone know of any updates on this in the 3.0 release?

Comment: For graph:`create (n:ent {id:'a'})-[:rel]->(:ent {id:'b'})-[:rel]->(o:ent {id:'c'})-[:rel]->(p:ent {id:'d'})-[:rel]->(:ent {id:'e'})-[:rel]->(n),(p)-[:rel]->(o)`, the query `MATCH path=(ent{id:'a'})-[:rel*0..]->(ent) WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) WHERE 1=length(filter(m in nodes(path)WHERE m=n))) RETURN path` gives `key not found:   UNNAMED25` error!!!

Answer (score 3):

my workaround for this:

```
START n = node(123), x=node(*)
MATCH p = shortestPath(n-[r:LIKES*..3]->x)
RETURN p;
```

see the example [in console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/jvc3a6)

Comment: This might work in the given example but I'm actually interested in all possible paths (not only the shortest one/s) within a given length  with no nodes repeated along the way. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In 2.3.0, use the following:

```
MATCH path = (start {id:2})<-[*1..]-(end {id:3}) 
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) where 
          1 = size(filter(m in nodes(path) where m=n))) 
RETURN start, LENGTH(path) AS length, EXTRACT(p in NODES(path) | p.id), end
ORDER BY length
```