# Neo4j: Conditions on Relationships with Depth

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### What I'm trying to do

Being relatively new to Neo4j, I'm trying to find certain nodes with **Cypher** in a **Neo4j** graph database. The nodes should be connected by a **chain of relationships of a certain type** with further **conditions on the relationships**:

```
// Cypher
START self = node(3413)
MATCH (self)<-[rel:is_parent_of*1..100]-(ancestors)
WHERE rel.some_property = 'foo'
RETURN DISTINCT ancestors
```

### What goes wrong

If I drop the depth part `*1..100`, the query works, but of course, then allows only one relationship between `self` and the `ancestors`.

But, if I allow the `ancestors` to be several steps away from `self` by introducing the depth `*1..100`, the query fails:

Error: **Expected `rel` to be a Map but it was a Collection**

I thought, maybe this syntax defines `rel` to be `is_parent_of*1..100` rather than defining `rel` to be a relationship of type `is_parent_of` and allowing a larger relationship depth.

So, I've tried to make my intentions clear by using parenthesis: `[(rel:is_parent_of)*1..100`. But this causes a *syntax error*.

I'd appreciate any help to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### Nomenclature

Calling `*1..100` **depth** originates in the nomenclature of the [neography ruby gem](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography), where this is done using the abstract `depth` method.

In neo4j, this is called **variable length relationships**, as can be seen here in the documentation: [MATCH / Variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/match/#varlength-rels).

### Reason for the error

The reason for the "*Expected `rel` to be a Map but it was a Collection*" error is, indeed, that `rel` does not refer to each single relationship but rather to the entire collection of matched relationships.

For an example, see here in the documentation: [MATCH / Relationship variable in variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/match/#rel-variable-in-varlength-rels).

### Solution

First, acknowledge that the identifier refers to a collection (i.e. a set of multiple items) and call it `rels` instead of `rel`. Then, in the `WHERE` clause, state that the condition has to apply to all `rel` items in the `rels` collection using the [`ALL` predicate](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/predicate/#functions-all).

```
// Cypher
START self = node(3413)
MATCH (self)<-[rels:is_parent_of*1..100]-(ancestors)
WHERE ALL (rel in rels WHERE rel.some_property = 'foo')
RETURN DISTINCT ancestors
```

The **ALL predicate** is explained here in the documentation: [Functions / Predicate Functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/predicate/#functions-all).

I was led to this solution by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948958/2066546) of a related question.

### Long query time

Unfortunately, asking for relationship properties does cost a lot of time. The above query with only a couple of nodes in the database, takes over 3000ms on my development machine.

Comment: great answer. to be exact one should add `WHERE ALL (rel in rels WHERE has(rel.some_property) AND rel.some_property = 'foo')`

Comment: All your links are broken.

Comment: Thanks Synch, I've updated the links to match the new neo4j documentation.