# Cypher: how to find all the chains of single nodes not repeated?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, chain, repeat

I want to find ALL the paths starting and ending from/to a specific node. I would like that each node in a path appears only once.

For example, in a graph like this:

```
(a)-[:REL]->(b)-[:REL]->(c)-[:REL]->(a)
(a)-[:REL]->(e)-[:REL]->(f)-[:REL]->(a)
(e)-[:REL]->(b)
```

grafically:

```
  e → b
 ↙ ↖ ↗ ↘
f → a ← c
```

Cypher code:

```
CREATE (a { name:'A' })-[:REL]->(b {name:'B'})-[:REL]->(c { name:'C' })
       -[:REL]->(a)-[:REL]->(e {name:'E'})-[:REL]->(f {name:'F'})-[:REL]->(a),
       (e)-[:REL]->(b)
```

I would like that the research of chains starting from (a) returns

```
(a)->(b)->(c)->(a)

(a)->(e)->(f)->(a)

(a)->(e)->(b)->(c)->(a)
```

while starting from (f) returns only

```
(f)->(a)->(e)->(f)
```

and NOT

```
(f)->(a)->(b)->(c)->(a)->(e)->(f)
```

because it passes twice through the node (a).

I tryied:

```
MATCH p=(a {name:'F'})-[:REL*1..]->(a) 
WHERE SINGLE(e1 IN TAIL(NODES(p)) WHERE SINGLE(e2 IN TAIL(NODES(p)) WHERE e1=e2))
RETURN p
```

but I've got no result.
The best I've been able to reach is to have no repetition of just the start node with this query:

```
MATCH p=(a {name:'F'})-[:REL*1..]->(a) 
WHERE SINGLE(e IN TAIL(NODES(p)) WHERE e=a)
RETURN p
```

but obviously it's not what I want because it returns also

```
(f)->(a)->(b)->(c)->(a)->(e)->(f)
```

that is a path involving the node (a) twice.

Can someone suggest me a solution?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. The version of Neo4j that I use is 2.0

Comment: Have you seen this answer from ages ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767748/returning-only-simple-paths-in-neo4j-cypher-query it may still be the only way and you might need to combine it with @FrobberOfBits answer, do you have to use Cypher?

Comment: Good advice, man. Below [@JohnMark13](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2477669/johnmark13) helped me giving me directly the code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the shoulders of those who came before I have come up with:

```
MATCH (a { name:'A' })
MATCH (a)-[p:REL]->(s)
WITH a, s
MATCH p = s-[r:REL*]->a
WITH [a] + nodes(p) AS ns
    WHERE ALL (n IN ns 
       WHERE 1=LENGTH(FILTER(m IN TAIL(ns) 
                             WHERE m = n)))
RETURN ns
```

It utilises the idea from @FrobberOfBits to perform the initial steps and then the query linked from Michael to perform the filter on the paths. I suppose that the TAIL could be left out, if you also left out:

```
WITH [a] + nodes(p) AS ns
```

Which would make the query this maybe:

```
MATCH (a { name:'A' })
MATCH (a)-[p:REL]->(s)
WITH a, s
MATCH p = s-[r:REL*]->a
WITH a, nodes(p) AS ns
WHERE ALL (n IN ns 
       WHERE 1=LENGTH(FILTER(m IN ns 
                             WHERE m = n)))
RETURN [a] + ns
```

The complicated or at least slightly hard to read part of the query is the `ALL` in combination with the `FILTER` which "basically" for all values in ns `(WHERE ALL (n in ns)` counts the number of occurences by comparing to all other values in the array (`m IN ns WHERE m = n`) and filters the result out completely if the resultant array does not contain a single element (`1=LENGTH`).

I added your example in the console [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=a6jh4i).

Comment: Great job, it does exactly what I want. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't forget to add Labels for your nodes to make it faster!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHunger surprised I was lazy and left that out, must have been rushing.

Answer (score 2):

So here is some data mocked up to copy your example:

```
$ create (a:T {label:"A"})-[:REL]->(b:T)-[:REL]->(c:T)-[:REL]->(a); 
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 3
Relationships created: 3
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 3
20 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (a:T {label:"A"})                                          
> CREATE a-[:REL]->(e:T)-[:REL]->(f:T)-[:REL]->(a);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 2
Relationships created: 3
Labels added: 2
27 ms
```

Now here's the query that will get you there (but it requires some explanation).

```
match (a:T {label: "A"})-[:REL]->(somethingElse),
      p=shortestPath((somethingElse)-[:REL*]->(a))
return p;
```

OK so basically it seems to me like you want the shortest path from (a) back to itself.  But that's tricky, because the shortest path from a node to itself is always the empty path, of length 0.  So if you do something like `shortestPath((a)-[:REL*]->(a))` the result will always be empty which isn't what you want.

So instead, I matched from one `:REL` hop to the next item (`somethingElse`) and then did the shortest path from that back to A.   The resulting returned path `p` is exactly the path you want, except that it's missing the original hop from `a-->somethingElse`.  As long as you take that extra hop into account, then the combination of `a-->somethingElse` with `p` should be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: The idea to use ShortestPath is good but omits all those paths longer than the shortest one where there are no repetitions. To give the idea I deepened my example above with an other relationship (e)-[:REL]->(b), in that case, starting from (a), I would like to retrieve also the path (a)->(e)->(b)->(c)->(a).

Comment: @FrobberOfBits For whatever reason, I would never have thought of this.  I Am now a bit graph smarter.