# Better Way to remove cycles from a path in neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j graph database version 2.1.7. Brief Details around data:
2 million nodes with 6 different type of nodes, 5 million relationships with only 5 different type of relationships and mostly connected graph but contains a few isolated subgraphs.

While resolving paths, i get cycles in path. And to restrict that, i used the solution shared in below:
[Returning only simple paths in Neo4j Cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767748/returning-only-simple-paths-in-neo4j-cypher-query)

Here is the Query, i am using:

```
MATCH (n:nodeA{key:905728}) 
MATCH path = n-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4*0..]->(c:nodeA)-[:rel5*0..1]->(b:nodeA) 
WHERE ALL(a in nodes(path) where 1=length (filter (m in nodes(path) where m=a))) 
and (length(EXTRACT (p in NODES(path)| p.key)) > 1) 
and ((exists ((c)-[:rel5]->(b)) and (not exists((b)-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4]->(:nodeA)) OR ANY (x in nodes(path) where (b)-[]->(x))))
    OR (not exists ((c)-[:rel5]->()) and (not exists ((c)-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4]->(:nodeA)) OR ANY (x in nodes(path) where (c)-[]->(x))))) 
RETURN distinct EXTRACT (rp in Rels(path)| type(rp)), EXTRACT (p in NODES(path)| p.key);
```

The above query solves mine requirement but is not cost effective and keeps running if is run for huge subgraph. I have used 'Profile' command to improve query performance from what i started with. But, now stuck at this point. The performance has improved but, not what i expected from neo4j :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that I have a solution, but I have a number of suggestions.  Some might speed things up, some might just make the query easier to read.

Firstly, rather than putting `exists ((c)-[:rel5]->(b))` in your `WHERE`, I believe you can put it in your `MATCH` like this:

```
MATCH path = n-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4*0..]->(c:nodeA)-[:rel5*0..1]->(b:nodeA), (c)-[:rel5]->(b)
```

I don't think you need the `exists` keyword.  I think you can just say, for example, `(NOT (b)-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4]->(:nodeA))`

I'd also suggest thinking about the [`WITH` clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html) for potential performance improvements.

A couple of notes about your variable paths: In `*0..` the `0` means that your potentially looking for a self-reference.  That may or may not be what you want.  Also, leaving the variable path open ended can often cause performance problems (as I think you're seeing).  If you can possibly cap it that may help.

Also, if you upgrade to 2.2.1, there are a number of built-in performance improvements with the 2.2.x line, but you also get visual `PROFILE`ing in the console and a new `EXPLAIN` command which both profiles and tells you the real performance of the query after running it.

One thing to consider too is that I don't think you're hitting performance boundaries of Neo4j but rather, perhaps, you're potentially hitting some boundaries of Cypher.  If so, I might suggest you do your querying with the Java APIs that Neo4j provides for better performance and more control.  This can either be via embedding your database if you're using a JVM-compatible language or by writing an [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) which lets you do your own querying in java but provide a custom REST API from the server

Comment: Thanks @Brian for the response. I will definitely work on the suggestions shared by you and share an update. On the *0.., You are right i have updated it *1... Not finding myself lucky enough to keep cap on the path and have to keep it open ended.

Answer (score 1):

Did a couple of more tweaks to my query as suggested above by Brian. And found improvement in query response time. Now, It takes almost 20% of time in execution compared to my original query and the current query makes almost 60% less db hits, compared to the query i shared earlier, during query execution. PFB the updated query:

```
MATCH (n:nodeA{key:905728}) 
MATCH path = n-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4*1..]->(c:nodeA)-[:rel5*0..1]->(b:nodeA) 
WHERE ALL(a in nodes(path) where 1=length (filter (m in nodes(path) where m=a))) 
and (length(path) > 0) 
and ((exists ((c)-[:rel5]->(b)) and (not ((c)-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4]->()) OR ANY (x in nodes(path) where (c)-[]->(x))))
    OR (not exists ((c)-[:rel5]->()) and (not ((c)-[:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4]->()) OR ANY (x in nodes(path) where (c)-[]->(x))))) 
RETURN distinct EXTRACT (rp in Rels(path)| type(rp)), EXTRACT (p in NODES(path)| p.key);
```

And observed dramatic improvement when capped the path from *1.. to *1..15. Also, removed one filter from query which too was taking longer time.
But, the query response time increased when queried on nodes having relationships more than 18-20 depths.

I would advise to use profile command oftenly to find pain points in your query. That would help you resolve the issues faster.
Thanks Brian.